# On intrinsic volumes

Tags: reference-request, convex-polytopes, convex-geometry, convexity

Let $\Gamma$ be a convex polytope in $\mathbb R^n$. The $k$-th intrinsic volume of $\Gamma$ is the number
$$
\text{v}_k(\Gamma)=\sum_{\Delta\in{\mathcal B}(\Gamma,k)}\text{vol}_k(\Delta)\psi_\Gamma(\Delta)\,,
$$
where $\mathcal B(\Gamma,k)$ is the set of $k$-dimensional faces of $\Gamma$, $\text{vol}_k(\Delta)$ the Lebesgue measure of $\Delta$ and $\psi_\Gamma(\Delta)$ the outer angle of $\Delta$.
Now consider the expression
$$
\text{v}_k^\varphi(\Gamma)=\sum_{\Delta\in{\mathcal B}(\Gamma,k)}\varphi(E_\Delta)\text{vol}_k(\Delta)\psi_\Gamma(\Delta)\,,
$$ 
where $\varphi$ is a real function defined on the Grassmannian manifold of $k$-dimensional $\mathbb R$-linear subspaces of $\mathbb R^n$ and $E_\Delta$ is the linear subspace parallel to the face $\Delta$.

For any $\varphi$, the functional $\text{v}^\varphi_k$ defines a $k$-homogeneous, translation invariant weak valuation on the space of convex polytopes of $\mathbb R^n$. If $\varphi$ is continuous and orthogonally invariant, $\text{v}^\varphi_k$ yields a continuous, $k$-homogeneous, rigid motion invariant valuation on convex bodies and so $\text{v}_k^\varphi$ becomes a multiple of the $\text{v}_k$.

As far as I know the functional $\text{v}_k^\varphi$ has been introduced by Kazarnovskii in the paper entitled *On the zeros of exponential sums.* (Soviet Math. Doklady 23.2 (1981), pp. 347–351), however it might have been defined before by someone else.

Can anybody provide further information about the valuation $\text{v}_k^\varphi$?

Comment: a remark is that these valuations are obtained by integrating universal differential forms on the normal bundle of the convex set. Namely, they are linear images of the normal cycle. The universal differential forms can be obtained by tweaking the ones giving usual intrinsic volumes by phi.

Comment: Thank you for tour comment. This weighted version of the intrinsic volume admits a corresponding mixed form generalizing mixed volume. I wonder if the mixed version verifies an Alexandroff-Fenchel inequality!

Comment: You may find relevant the following recent paper by Thomas Wannerer https://arxiv.org/pdf/1907.11606.pdf. In Thm 1.2 he characterizes those functions $\phi$ on the Grassmannian for which the valuation you wrote extends by continuity in Hausdorff metric to all convex compact sets.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing me to this paper.